# objective-c iPhone4 segmented button under Phone table refresh

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I have a segmented button in NavBar at top of tableView like the one used in the iPhone when you select 'Recents'. The phone does not bring in a new view but simply refreshes the table cells with new objects from selected array when button is pressed. I would like to do the same but cannot figure out how to cleanly swap the table rows without a new tableView. I already use tabBar for some other purpose so using the navBar would work better.

Answer (score 0):

The phone app is using the animated addition/removal of cells to achieve the effect. Please see the Session 128 from WWDC 2010 for details.

http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

There are also numerous examples of using that API on the Apple Developer website.

Also the tags for your question are off, instead of NSArray etc you should probably tag the question with 'Cocoa Touch' and/or 'ios'.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I will change tag next time to be more inline with protocol.